# What does "mounting fs with errors" mean in dmesg and what to do after that?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, fsck

I run dmesg and this is what I see:

```
EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
```

Here is the stuff in context

```
EXT3-fs (sdd1): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sdc1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Adding 4194296k swap on /dev/sdd2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4194296k SSD
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3-fs (loop0): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT3-fs (loop0): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
```

what is e2fsck anyway? How to run it?

Answer (score 11):

First of all, as far as I can tell, your disk is fine and everyone should relax. This is a safety feature, you can set a disk to be checked on each mount or after a specified number of mounts. If you have not done so, your system will give you the warnings you show, letting you know that it has been a while since the disk was last checked and that it would be a good idea to check it for errors (that's what `e2fsck` does).

Note that the error says:

> **warning**: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is **recommended**

That's a warning, not an error, and a recommendation, not a command.

The `warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended` is a bit more worrying but can probably be fixed by `e2fsck`.

This all comes down to [`/etc/fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Field_definitions) options. A typical `fstab` partition entry looks like this:

```
# <file system>       <dir>         <type>    <options>             <dump> <pass>
UUID=123-456-ABC-DEF   /             ext4      defaults,noatime      0      1
```

The last field, `pass`, specifies how/when the disk should be checked for errors. If it is set to `0`, the drive will never be checked, if set to `1`, it will be checked on each boot and if set to `2` or more, it will be checked each time it has been mounted more than a specified (30 by default) number of times without being checked.

Given the warnings you observe, my guess is that you have set it to `0` in your `/etc/fstab`. The recommended values are `1` for your `/`partition and `2` or higher for everything else. If set at a value greater than `1`, the system will check your drive for errors every 30 mounts. To change the frequency of checking (for example, to check every 20 mounts), run:

```
tune2fs -c 20 /dev/sda1
```

So, while @vfbsilva's answer is perfectly correct, it would be much easier to simply edit your `/etc/fstab`, change the `pass` value for the partition in question to 2 and reboot. That should cause the drive to be checked and the warnings to go away.

Comment: seems stange that the error is mentioned before the count of mounts, does it matters in this contexts?

Comment: @vfbsilva they refer to different disks, the `mounting fs with errors` is about `sda1` and the count warning is about `sdb1`.

Answer (score 5):

Seems your disk is damaged I recommend you to stop using it. Fsck stands for file system check which is a tool to repair problems in file systems. As the usage of this tool can result in dataloss if some details are not observed (i.e. running it on a mounted file system) strongly recommend you to read this [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck) And google a bit before taking any decision.

**Do not run fsck on a live or mounted file system**. fsck is used to check and optionally repair one or more Linux file systems. Running fsck on a mounted filesystem can usually result in disk / data corruption. So please do not do it. You have two choices

1. Take down system to single user mode and unmout system
2. Boot from the installation CD into rescue mode

Following are the relevant steps in each case:

1. Take down system to single user mode and unmout system

   - Use init (process control initialization ) command to change runlevel 1 (singe user mode)
   - Use umount command to unmount `/home` file system
   - Run the filesystem check using the `fsck` command

Let us say you would like to run `fsck` on `/home` (/dev/sda3):

```
init 1
umount /home
umount /dev/sda
fsck /homeOR
fsck /dev/sda3
```

OR

```
e2fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

2.Boot from the installation CD into rescue mode

If you are using Cent OS/Fedora Core/RHEL Linux, boot from first CD and at boot prompt type:

```
boot: linux rescue nomount
```

Now make new node for disk and partition 3:

```
mknod /dev/sda
mknod /dev/sda3
fsck /dev/sda3
```

OR

```
e2fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

Don't forget to reboot the system:

```
exit
reboot
```

Comment: Is there a way to reboot and specify to run efsck during reboot? I've heard about shutdown -rf could this be hardware? My provider insist that the problem is in user (me) rather than hardware.

Comment: /home1 is not the system file. However, I got "maximal mount count reached" on all other files too and I do not know how to fix that. None are the system file.

Comment: if I type umount /home1 given that sda/sda1 is mounted as /home1, that means /dev/sda will be unmounted right? sda1 is the only partition in sda

Comment: Why is it mounted more than x times? What's the limit? What's the problem? The drives are new. I only mount each once.

Comment: @JimThio it is mounted every time you reboot. See my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. There was a bug that make things rebooted again and again. That's why. Anyway what about "mounting fs with errors"?

Comment: But I have done shutdown -rf several time. Why I still get that error?

Comment: @JimThio did you try changing the `fstab` as suggested in my answer? (Also, please answer my comment with a comment to my answer so we don't take over this one.)

Comment: disk != filesystem, the filesystem seems damaged, but that does not imply a disk failure.

Answer (score 1):

DANGER....DANGER....

To avoid losing information or compromising your disk further, IMMEDIATELY dismount the affected disks and run e2fsck as directed!!!   You should never mount and use a damaged disk.

If you fail to do this your disk is getting more and more corrupted and might become unsalvageable.

Then of course you'll have to rely on those fine backups you have been using.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when mounting this device the kernel detected that your file system has not been cleanly unmounted, so it might have errors.

You have to first unmount it and then run the filesystem check like `e2fsck /dev/sda1`. This will check if there are any errors, and if so it asks you whether it should fix them.